# Android device not mounting (neither USB nor Blutooth)

Tags: usb, file-transfer, usb-drivers, mount, bluetooth-pairing

I have an Android KitKat 4.4.2 Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo. All was working fine, and I could mount the device and copy files from the device to my Windows 7 PC. Now when I disconnect or insert the USB cable to my Android device I hear the ta-da, ra-ra sounds, and the hard drive LED on my Sony VAIO PC goes orange and then blinks orange for a while, but the Computer location in `explorer.exe` does not show my device as it used to (a folder used to connect also used to pop up). And when I try to connect via `fsquirt.exe` on the PC and click "Receive files" and on my Blutooth network device I click on the PC name, then the PC shows a number for the pairing, but such number never appears on my device.

So I can connect via neither blutooth, neither USB. Both are enabled at the top of the notification drawer.

What could be wrong here, and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to transfer my files to a temporary directory on Google Drive and download it from Google Chrome to my Desktop and then make use of them from there. Anyways, a couple of days later my Windows 7 OS (Sony VAIO) completely crashed (gray screen). I forced the laptop off with the off switch and after returning to it after a walk and turining it on, it said, `No Operating System found`

So it is possible that the mounting was not working because the computer hard-drive was about to crash.